# search though all tables extended from @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have and issue with searching in entities that are extended from @MappedSuperclass. I created a class PhoneBook and extended 2 entities from it: FirstPhoneBook and SecondPhoneBook. The structure looks the following:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PhoneBook {
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "first_phone_book")
public class FirstPhoneBook extends PhoneBook {
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "second_phone_book")
public class SecondPhoneBook extends PhoneBook {
...
```

These tables are absolutely similar. I discribe all fields in PhoneBook class, childs have only default constructor in it. External system sends a phone number as a parameter. Depending on whether tables contain such number or not my system responds with a word.

The question is: how can I search separately in each table that is extended from @MappedSuperclass without hardcoding each child class name?

I could only find variants of search by value like that:

`currentSession.get(Employee.class, theId);`

but there is explicit call to entity class. I want this to be extendable without need to write new DAO for each new entity added. Current method signature looks the following:

`public <T extends PhoneBook> T findByNumber(String number);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is polymorphic queries, i.e. queries that reference the parent class. The [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-mapped-superclass) says this is not well supported when using `@MappedSuperclass` inheritance:

> Because the `@MappedSuperclass` inheritance model is not mirrored at the database level, it’s not possible to use polymorphic queries referencing the `@MappedSuperclass` when fetching persistent objects by their base class.

If polymorphic queries are frequently used, it's better to use the [table per class](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-table-per-class) inheritance strategy:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class PhoneBook {
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "first_phone_book")
public class FirstPhoneBook extends PhoneBook {
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "second_phone_book")
public class SecondPhoneBook extends PhoneBook {
...
```

You can then fetch an entity using the superclass:

```
PhoneBook phoneBook = currentSession.get(PhoneBook.class, theId);
```

and Hibernate would typically use a UNION to do the query with both tables.

This being said, even with `@MapperSuperclass`, Hibernate can still query all tables for classes that extend the parent class. You can use the following JPA query (note that it uses the fully qualified class name of the parent class):

```
Query<PhoneBook> query = currentSession.createQuery("from " + PhoneBook.class.getName() +
                                                    " where id = :id", PhoneBook.class);
query.setParameter("id", theId);
```

The difference is that here it's not querying an entity, but just all classes that extend a parent class. Also in this case, unlike with the table-per-class strategy, Hibernate will not use a UNION, but send a query to each table, in this case two separate SQL queries instead of one.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks a lot. Don't want to use @Inheritance cause of new table. Task is to have only two those similar tables.

Comment: And can I somehow select only from one table that i need and not both at the same time?

Comment: @Evillain I don't think the table-per-class strategy will create a third table, only for the concrete classes. To select from a specific table, you can specify explicitly the subclass in the query instead of the parent class.

Comment: @M Anouti the problem with explicitly calling the subclass is that if i add a third table, i'll need to modify all the code to work with third table. Is there a way to work with the highest possible  abstraction to have horizontal scalability?

Comment: @Evillain if you mean by "highest possible abstraction" the parent abstract class, then yes that's what the polymorphic query is supposed to do.

Comment: @M Anouti ok, one more question then with inheritance table-per-class strategy. if i annotate so my PhoneBook current superclass instead of @MappedSuperClass and i want to select specific data based on number as an id, how can i check whether such data is in both tables or only in one? And i'll have no need to create explicitly third table for superclass?

Comment: @Evillain You're implying that the number (I assume it's the phone number) is not unique, i.e. it can be present in both tables. In this case it is not an identifier, so you can't call `session.get()` with the value. You can query using `Query<PhoneBook> query = session.createQuery("from PhoneBook where num = :num", PhoneBook.class);`.  Then you can check the number of entries returned in the list: `List<PhoneBook> resultList = query.getResultList();`, so you can examine their actual type.

Comment: @MA Glad I found your answer. I just have one question. You said by executing the query manually (last query), JPA will then look for tables one by one instead of union. How does that work? I have huge performance issues with union. I just want JPA to look for all child tables one by one and return the data as batches. Now the batch part can be achieved by Pageable. But I want guarantee that JPA will only look one table at a time when fetching data. Is it possible with your last approach?

Comment: @MA my question is detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73191506/10582056 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73193653/10582056