# Database pressure on Polymorphic queries

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have used polymorphic fetching in JPA with over 5 child classes. The executed query is given below:

```
explain SELECT
       ohlcrawbea0_.trade_time AS trade_ti3_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.avg_price AS avg_pric4_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.best_ask_price AS best_ask5_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.best_bid_price AS best_bid6_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.bid_vwap AS bid_vwap7_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.change AS change8_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.close AS close9_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.high AS high10_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.low AS low11_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.open AS open12_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.volume AS volume13_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.vwap AS vwap14_11_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.closing_best_ask AS closing_1_1_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.closing_best_bid AS closing_2_1_,
       ohlcrawbea0_.clazz_ AS clazz_
FROM (
         SELECT
             ticker_serial,
                trade_time,
                avg_price,
                best_ask_price,
                best_bid_price,
                bid_vwap,
                change,
                CLOSE,
                high,
                low,
                OPEN,
                volume,
                vwap,
                NULL::numeric AS closing_best_ask,
                NULL::numeric AS closing_best_bid,
                1 AS clazz_
         FROM dfn_history.var_int_ohlc_5
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
             ticker_serial,
                trade_time,
                avg_price,
                best_ask_price,
                best_bid_price,
                bid_vwap,
                change,
                CLOSE,
                high,
                low,
                OPEN,
                volume,
                vwap,
                NULL::numeric AS closing_best_ask,
                NULL::numeric AS closing_best_bid,
                2 AS clazz_
         FROM dfn_history.var_int_ohlc_15
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ticker_serial,
                trade_time,
                avg_price,
                best_ask_price,
                best_bid_price,
                bid_vwap,
                change,
                CLOSE,
                high,
                low,
                OPEN,
                volume,
                vwap,
                NULL::numeric AS closing_best_ask,
                NULL::numeric AS closing_best_bid,
                3 AS clazz_
         FROM dfn_history.var_int_ohlc_60
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ticker_serial,
                trade_time,
                avg_price,
                best_ask_price,
                best_bid_price,
                bid_vwap,
                change,
                CLOSE,
                high,
                low,
                OPEN,
                volume,
                vwap,
                NULL::numeric AS closing_best_ask,
                NULL::numeric AS closing_best_bid,
                4 AS clazz_
         FROM dfn_history.var_int_ohlc_30
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ticker_serial,
                trade_time,
                avg_price,
                best_ask_price,
                best_bid_price,
                bid_vwap,
                change,
                CLOSE,
                high,
                low,
                OPEN,
                volume,
                vwap,
                closing_best_ask,
                closing_best_bid,
                5 AS clazz_
         FROM dfn_history.intraday_ohlc
     ) ohlcrawbea0_
WHERE ticker_serial in (select ticker_serial from dfn_universal_data.tickers where source_id = 'NSDQ' and status = 1 limit 100)
limit 500;
```

This is the corresponding JPA method.

```
Slice<OhlcRawBean<? extends OhlcBean>> findByIdSourceIdAndIdTickerIdIn(
            String sourceId,
            Set<String> tickerId,
            PageRequest pageRequest
    );
```

You can see that it unions all child tables and limits by given amount in page request. I use Postgresql.

My supervisor worries that using a polymorphic query may put too much pressure on the database. Is it the actual case here?

**UPDATE**
Here is the execution plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..1582.89 rows=500 width=106)
  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.56..588621630.17 rows=185998035 width=106)
        Join Filter: (var_int_ohlc_5.ticker_serial = tickers.ticker_serial)
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..30586726.15 rows=688881610 width=111)
              ->  Seq Scan on var_int_ohlc_5  (cost=0.00..3697863.28 rows=97251928 width=147)
              ->  Seq Scan on var_int_ohlc_15  (cost=0.00..1663885.60 rows=45498860 width=148)
              ->  Seq Scan on var_int_ohlc_60  (cost=0.00..607653.98 rows=17155198 width=148)
              ->  Seq Scan on var_int_ohlc_30  (cost=0.00..979599.08 rows=27480508 width=148)
```

I could not add all 500 lines of plan because SO does not allow large code blocks.

Is there a way to optimize this polymorphic fetching? How can I tell jpa/hibernate to not union all tables but to fetch from every single table?

Comment: Postgres should be able to push the WHERE condition into the UNION parts. You can always confirm that through the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: Check my update plse. Still the time taken is too much. Is there a way to run the same queries one by one without doing a union

Comment: The execution plan is better shared as formatted text generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` - the screenshot hides many important details.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've added the start of EP. Please check.

Comment: The query plan does not seem to match the SQL query. The query plan says you are doing a join against some table with the column `ticker_serial`. Apart from that, I don't see a filter node for the two ´where` clause predicates. Nobody will be able to help you if you post confusing partial/wrong code and plans...

Comment: @ChristianBeikov I just updated with same query and results. Plse check.

Comment: Your database assumes that 185_998_035 rows of the union over all tables, which is roughly 1/3 of the whole data, will match the `where` clause condition. I don't know what kind of column `ticker_serial` is, but if it is a primary key your DB doesn't seem to understand that this query is highly selective, which implies wrong statistics. I'm no PostgreSQL professional though, so you should really consult your DBA about this. Maybe this can be fixed by running analyze on the tables or creating some extended statistics.