# Force JPA to not use union and fetch tables one by one

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 5 similar tables from which I need to execute a same query and fetch data in pages. I have used polymorphic queries (have super abstract class and used `@Inheritance` to fetch all rows automatically)

But this approach has problems as noted here: [Database pressure on Polymorphic queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73191506/10582056)

The issue is that the queries use `union all` which makes DB to search through millions of rows just to get 500 results. So instead I want to execute this serially.

**When I execute the method JPA will go to first table; fetch data in pages; if the data fetching is complete then go to second table and so on...**

Right now with union, I have ton of pressure on database. With this new approach, I could have less pressure as only one table is accessed at once.

I do not know a way to do this without changing the setup I have right now. For example right now I have it like this:

```
public interface OhlcDao extends JpaRepository<AbstractOhlc, OhlcId> {

    Slice<OhlcRawBean<? extends OhlcBean>> findByIdSourceIdAndIdTickerIdIn(
            String sourceId,
            Set<String> tickerId,
            PageRequest pageRequest
    );

}
```

The method uses union to fetch data which I do not like.

Is there a way to make this work in JPA or Hibernate by changing any internal code (aka without changing my setup, so similar method does not use unions)

Comment: Using `union all` is the only "sane" approach I can think of, which you could use to make this work. I'm pretty sure you are simply missing indexes for your where clause predicates. Consult your DBA about the query plan and let him figure out this. If you think there is a better SQL Hibernate could render, then please share this with us.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov the where clauses refer to the primary keys which are always indexed in Postgresql. I think what happens is that EDB first unions all 5 tables -> then do a search with where -> then do a limit. So each time I get a pageable, it does it all which result in scanning through lot more records. Check my SQL and Execution plan in the other question (link in post)

Comment: AFAIK PostgreSQL should be capable of pushing down predicates. Like I wrote before, you should consult a DBA and ask why PostgreSQL is behaving this way. Most likely, you are missing indexes or statistics are wrong.